# How to pass data from child to parent view or between child views?

Tags: c#, silverlight

Hello
I am currently migrating a C# WPF project to Silverlight and I stumbled on a problem also related to my lack of Silverlight knowledge:

I have my MainPage.xaml which accepts several Views, for example

**I want to pass a String from View1 to View2 programatically. Depending on the value that is passed from View1 , View2 will change. I don't know how to access/transmit values between views**(or atleast a workaround - back to parent, and then to the other child? )

I have researched this topic for some time now, but I couldn't figure it out. If my question allready has an answer somewhere on forum || my question is poorly written || my question is stupid || other cases , I am deeply sorry - don't want to irritate/offend anyone.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean with 'View' here?  ViewModel, UserControl?

Comment: ViewModel. Im referring to something similar to the default Silverlight Business Application new project which has Home and About views. How can I programatically pass values from Home to About for example?

Comment: Better make it more concrete, with a few code samples. There shouldn't be much difference from WPF

Answer (score 0):

Ok by view, you mean navigation pages.

Using navigation application, there is many ways to do that but I think the best way is using url parameters (just as html parameters) if your parameters are simple string values, then you can retrieve the value from code using

```
this.NavigationContext.QueryString["ProductId"];
```

for more details check here :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838245(VS.95).aspx#Y3804

If you need to pass complex types, use a public property in your view.